# Storing large json strings to database + hash

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I need to store large (30K uncompressed) JSON strings in my database. I am using gzip to compress the string and therefore MySQL's BLOB data type to store it. However, only 5% of all requests contain unique data and only unique data needs to be stored in the database.

My approach is as follows.

1. `array_multisort` data (array `[a, b, c]` is virtually the same as `[a, c, b]`).
2. `json_encode` data (`json_encode` is faster than `serialize`; we need string array representation for step **3**).
3. `sha1` data (slower than `md5`, though less possible the collisions).
4. Check if the hash exists in the database.
5. - Exists: do not insert the data.
   - New: gzip the data and store it along the hash.

Is there anything about this (apart from storing JSON data to the database in the first place) that sounds fishy or should be done a different way?

The database has roughly 1kk unique records being created every month.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach to me

Comment: 30k uncompressed. Naturally, far less gziped since it is plain-text data.

Comment: It might make more sense to keep the data in files and only store hashes to keep track of current entries. The rest seems fine. Though I would use unique key (or maybe just an index) with two fields: `size` and `hash`. The `size` would have lower cardinality and it would speed up the lookup.

Comment: I assume you have looked into tools like Memcached and decided they don't do what you need?  Caching large datasets is a common problem, so excellent tools exist already - you should be rolling your own only as a last resort.

Comment: @dimo414 Memcached isn't an option, nor is NoSQL. I am limited to MySQL and PHP for this. The question is only how to make the most of it.

Comment: What about storing the `data` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are doing is some sort of L2/persistent/distributed cache.

The overall process is quite right, but you should consider using a hash algorithm that fits your environment with the best performance.

While MD5 has 128 bits, SHA-1 has 160. The difference is huge! While MD5 may have 2^128 (~3.4x10^38), SHA-1 may have 2^160 (~1.4x10^48). Do you think that you would have collisions using MD5?

In the *best case scenario*, assuming 1 million unique records per month (10^6), you would need around 3.4x10^32 months to have a collision. Of course these are theoretical values, even as MD5 doesn't distribute evenly over 2^128.

Also, if you consider that old values should be discarded (like an LRU algorithm), as they are no longer relevant to be stored, you could even use a simpler and faster hash algorithm.

If, by any means, performance and/or storage capacity aren't issues, stick with SHA-1, which will have much longer duration with much less chance of collision.

Cheers!